# How to compare with last data in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

There's a data list with stock info from the server, and I use them like following

```
<div class="stockname">microsoft</div><div class="stockprice">1000</div>
<div class="stockname">yahoo</div><div class="stockprice">300</div>
<div class="stockname">google</div><div class="stockprice">800</div>
<div class="stockname">facebook</div><div class="stockprice">600</div>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function startRefresh() {
  $(".stockprice").load(location.href+" .stockprice");
  $('.stockprice').fadeOut(500);
  $('.stockprice').fadeIn(500);
 } 
$(function() {
   startRefresh(); 
   setInterval("startRefresh()", 10000); 
});
</script>
```

And I want to refresh the stockprice colums every 10 seconds, and also compare the current stock price with last time, if current stock price is different from last time, the corresponding `div` section should blink, if the price is the same, do nothing, any ideas?

Comment: you didnt specify what variable in the response is holding the price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a string `"startRefresh()"` to the `setInterval()`, you need to pass a function. Correcting it, here is how you can solve your problem:

```
function startRefresh() {
  var previousValue = $('.stockprice').text();

  $(".stockprice").load(location.href + " .stockprice", function() {
    var newValue = $('.stockprice').text();

    if (previousValue !== newValue) {
      $('.stockprice').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
   setInterval(function() { startRefresh(); }, 10000); 
});
```

Basically, you can check the existing value of the element using `text()`. Store it in a temp variable before loading new content. After the load, you can compare the new value with the old value. If they aren't same, flash the element.